# Calculating Points for Category and Sub-Category Combined

Tags: mysql, sum

I'm currently using a points system that uses the query below to list who has the most points in a category or any category directly below it (using 'links_to' and 'links_from' in the 'category_relations table').

```
SELECT  u.name, 
        pa.user_id, 
        SUM(IF(pa.plus = '1', pa.points_amount, 0)) - 
        SUM(IF(pa.plus = '0', pa.points_amount, 0)) AS points
FROM    points_awarded pa, Users u
WHERE   u.user_id = pa.user_id AND 
        (
           category_id = '" . $category_id . "' OR 
           category_id IN
               (
                   SELECT links_to
                   FROM category_relations
                   WHERE links_from = '" . $category . "'
               )
        ) 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY points DESC 
LIMIT 50
```

What I'm now looking to do is switch this query to look for all categories for a specific user instead of looking for all users for a specific category. Below is the query i've tried to use, but this only includes points for the category and not sub categories directly below.

```
SELECT   u.name, 
         pa.user_id, 
         pa.category_id,
         SUM(IF(pa.plus = '1', pa.points_amount, 0)) - 
         SUM(IF(pa.plus = '0',pa.points_amount, 0)) AS points
FROM     points_awarded pa, Users u
WHERE    u.user_id = pa.user_id AND 
         u.user_id = '" . $user_id . "'
GROUP BY pa.category_id 
ORDER BY points DESC 
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: How is a category defined as a subcategory of another category?
Can you show your tables structure (just the tables and columns that are useful here).

Comment: Yes please show your table structure and perhaps some sample data. This will go great lengths in helping us provide you an effective solution.

Comment: @KayKay sub-categories are defined by the category_relations table, containing links_to (sub category id) and links_from (category id) fields.

Comment: @john - why is it you still haven't posted the table structures involved in this post? The community has asked for it numerous times. Is it because your organization won't allow you to share that type of information? If so, we'd all understand, but we're just trying to help and need a better picture.

Answer (score 5):

## Solution

From your example queries, I was able to derive a simplification of your table structure which provided me with just enough information to answer your question. You can use this solution:

```
SELECT   a.user_id, 
         a.name, 
         b.category_id,
         SUM(IF(d.plus = '1', d.points_amount, 0)) -
         SUM(IF(d.plus = '0', d.points_amount, 0)) AS points
FROM     Users a
JOIN     points_awarded b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
JOIN     (
         SELECT links_from, links_to 
         FROM   category_relations 
         UNION
         SELECT links_from, links_from
         FROM   category_relations 
         ) c ON b.category_id = c.links_from
JOIN     points_awarded d ON c.links_to = d.category_id
WHERE    a.user_id = $user_id
GROUP BY a.user_id,
         a.name,
         b.category_id
ORDER BY points DESC
LIMIT    50
```

Where `$user_id` is the user id parameter to the query.

---

## Breakdown

Basically the key component of this query is the way we select the `category_relations` table.

Since you want the sum of subcategory points (by each parent category) ***plus*** their respective parent category's points, we can tack on the parent category vertically via `UNION` and essentially make it a subcategory of itself. This will then factor nicely into the `GROUP BY` and `SUM`.

Say we have some (simplified) data like this:

```
Users
------------------
user_id  |  name
433      |  Zane
```

---

```
points_awarded
------------------
user_id  |  category_id  |  plus  |  points_amount
433      |  1            |  1     |  785
433      |  2            |  1     |  871
433      |  3            |  1     |  236
433      |  4            |  0     |  64
433      |  5            |  0     |  12
433      |  7            |  1     |  897
433      |  8            |  1     |  3
433      |  9            |  0     |  48
433      |  10           |  1     |  124
433      |  14           |  0     |  676
```

---

```
category_relations
------------------
links_from | links_to
1          | 2
1          | 3
1          | 4
5          | 8
5          | 9
7          | 10
7          | 14
```

---

In order to differentiate between parent and sub categories, the query does a self-cross-reference join on the `points_awarded` table using the two fields in the `category_relations` table.

If we just joined on the `category_relations` table as is without the `UNION`, our resulting join would look like something like (columns simplified):

#### points_awarded ⋈ (links_from) category_relations ⋈ (links_to) points_awarded:

```
category_id  |  points_amount  |  category_id  |  points_amount
1            |  785            |  2            |  871
1            |  785            |  3            |  236
1            |  785            |  4            |  64
5            |  12             |  8            |  3
5            |  12             |  9            |  48
7            |  897            |  10           |  124
7            |  897            |  14           |  676
```

As you can see, the left-most `category_id` is the parent categories, and the right-most `category_id` is the respective subcategories. We can easily group on the first category_id and `SUM` the second `points_amount`...

But wait, we need the parent categorys' `points_amount` to be included too! How do we get the first `points_amount` distinctly into the second `points_amount`? This is where the `UNION` comes into play.

Before we perform our self-cross-reference join, we subselect the `category_relations` table so as to alter it slightly:

```
SELECT links_from, links_to FROM category_relations
UNION
SELECT links_from, links_from FROM category_relations
```

Which then results in:

```
category_relations (subselected)
------------------
links_from | links_to
1          | 1       <-- parent category
1          | 2
1          | 3
1          | 4
5          | 5       <-- parent category
5          | 8
5          | 9
7          | 7       <-- parent category
7          | 10
7          | 14
```

Where we've essentially made each parent category a subcategory of itself. We use the result of this in our join which should then produce:

```
category_id  |  points_amount  |  category_id  |  points_amount
1            |  785            |  1            |  785
1            |  785            |  2            |  871
1            |  785            |  3            |  236
1            |  785            |  4            |  64
5            |  12             |  5            |  12             
5            |  12             |  8            |  3
5            |  12             |  9            |  48
7            |  897            |  7            |  897            
7            |  897            |  10           |  124
7            |  897            |  14           |  676
```

There, ***NOW*** the parent category is factored into the `SUM` and we can now group on the first `category_id`, summing the second `points_amount` (ignore the first `points_amount` at this point as it is irrelevant), giving you the desired output.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, however i seem to be getting strange results. I'm only getting 3 results back (instead of 20+) and all with inflated values, I'm not sure if this method is returning any sub category of main category instead of just the sub-category directly below it?

Comment: @john, this is why we need to see your table schema and example data so that we can formulate an accurate solution to your problem; otherwise we are just shooting blind hoping it's what you need. Are you storing the combination of `user_id -> category_id` more than once in the `points_awarded` table? (In which case this would call for an intermediate `GROUP BY` and `SUM`). What is the `plus` field for? Does the category hierarchy go more than one level deep?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure there's an easier way to do this with joining to the category_relations table but its difficult not seeing any visual examples of the tables... I think this should work:

```
SELECT   u.name
        ,pa.user_id
        ,pa.category_id,
        SUM(IF(pa.plus = '1', pa.points_amount, 0)) - SUM(IF(pa.plus = '0',pa.points_amount, 0)) AS points
FROM        points_awarded pa
JOIN        Users u
USING       (user_id)
WHERE       category_id IN(
    SELECT      links_to
    FROM        category_relations
    WHERE       links_from = (
        SELECT      category_id
        FROM        points_awarded
        WHERE       user_id = '" . $user_id . "'
    )
)       
GROUP BY    pa.category_id
ORDER BY    points DESC
LIMIT       50
```

You weren't seeing subcategories in your posted example above because you weren't including records from the category_relations table. Instead of finding linked categories by the queried category_id, we're using the sub-sub-query to find all category_ids associated with the user. Give this a shot, and if this isnt right, please post some small snippets showing the table data.

Comment: looking at that again, I think the above would only get sub-categories and not original categories (since the IN is only linked to categories and not the linking category). But if a user had any interaction with the sub-category they should already have a user_id - sub-category row in points_awarded? Or do they get points for subcategories too even when they are only associated with the parent category?